# TextView does not appear when put it between two vertical guidelines in constraintLayout, Android Studio, Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview

When I put a TextView, make the top constraint on the parent, and its left and right constraints on two vertical guidelines, and then run the app, the textview disappears

I tried to restart the app, and restart Android Studio

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.